# So I wanted to make a trig solver in javascript?

Tags: javascript, math

But when I ran the `Math.cos(1)` It was different than the cos my calculator returned, would that make a difference with the answer? Will it return a different value?

On my calculator I tested `4 x cos(3)` and in js I tested `4 * Math.cos(3)`.

They were both different, in js these were the first few numbers `-3.9599` and on my calc `3.9945`

Comment: Are you using the right units? (degrees or radians) - that would be the first thing to check...

Comment: Why would you post a question like this and NOT supply the two different answers that you got?

Comment: On my calculator I tested `4 x cos(3)` and in js I tested `4 * Math.cos(3)`

Comment: They were both different, in js these were the first few numbers `-3.9599` and on my calc `3.9945`

Answer (score 2):

`Math.cos()` expects it's argument in radians. Your calculator is set for degrees.

cos(3) radians = -0.9899

cos(3) degrees = 0.9986

Answer (score 2):

[`Math.cos(x)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/cos), where `x` is *A number given in unit of radians.*

I'm assuming you're expecting `0.999(...)` [degrees] but are seeing `0.540(...)` [radians] coming from JavaScript.

But, you're in luck! There is a questions on SO regarding [how to convert to degrees](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9705123/how-can-i-get-sin-cos-and-tan-to-return-degrees-instead-of-radians).

Comment: what about the `sin-1` is there a function for that?

Comment: [`Math.asin`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/asin)? (arcsin is what you're looking for)

Answer (score 0):

can you post the 2 values that you got? I blindly think you're dealing with http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Floating_point#Accuracy_problems . And if this is the issue, I think you will have to check if the results are within a certain tolerance, as Alnitak said here: [How can i make the php cos function return the correct value?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6243430/how-can-i-make-the-php-cos-function-return-the-correct-value)